# Convert JavaScript to date object to MySQL date format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

I'm trying to use JavaScript to convert a date object into a valid MySQL date - what is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update:** Here in 2021, Date.js hasn't been maintained in **years** and is not recommended, and Moment.js is in "maintenance only" mode. We have the built-in [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat), [`Intl.RelativeTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat), and (soon) [`Temporal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) instead, probably best to use those. Some useful links are linked from [Moment's page on entering maintenance mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

---

**Old Answer:**

Probably best to use a library like [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) (although that hasn't been maintained in years) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

But to do it manually, you can use `Date#getFullYear()`, `Date#getMonth()` (it starts with 0 = January, so you probably want + 1), and `Date#getDate()` (day of month). Just pad out the month and day to two characters, e.g.:

```
(function() {
    Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;
    function Date_toYMD() {
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(this.getFullYear());
        month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(this.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }
})();
```

Usage:

```
var dt = new Date();
var str = dt.toYMD();
```

Note that the function has a name, which is useful for debugging purposes, but because of the anonymous scoping function there's no pollution of the global namespace.

That uses local time; for UTC, just use the UTC versions (`getUTCFullYear`, etc.).

Caveat: I just threw that out, it's completely untested.

Comment: MomentJS also now "a legacy project" in their own words https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ so best is actually to directly use `Date`.

Comment: @JimDriscoll - Yeah, or the upcoming `Temporal`.

Answer (score 162):

To get the date:

```js
const date = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)
console.log(date) //2015-07-23
```

For datetime:

```js
const datetime = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
console.log(datetime) //2015-07-23 11:26:00
```

Note that the resulting date/datetime will always be in the UTC timezone.

Comment: OP wants a MySQL DATE object, not a DATETIME, so you need "/T.*/" instead of "'T'". apart from that, wondering why this is not the most upvoted answer?

Comment: Why Not this?

(new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10)

Comment: A slight variation on the same theme:
``(new Date()).toISOString().split(/[T\.]/).slice(0,2).join(' ')``

Comment: Just a note that this won't work for years over 9999 ;)

Comment: When i did this (new Date(str_date)).toISOString().substring(0, 10) the date became day before the str_date. not accurate when parsing from string to date

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yes, you need to be careful with that, because the result is in the UTC timezone

Comment: @KubaHoluj I'll make sure to add a note about that in the comments for the poor sod reviewing my code in the year 10000

Comment: Best and most simplest answer i've seen so far.

Comment: What will happen in the year 10000 :O ;)

Answer (score 11):

The shortest version of [this answer by Chris Mayhew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453710):

```js
/**
 * MySQL date
 * @param {Date} [date] Optional date object
 * @returns {string}
 */
function mysqlDate(date = new Date()) {
  return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

const date = mysqlDate();
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just edit the string instead:

```js
const date = new Date();
const myDate = date.toISOString().replace("T", " ");
const myDateString = myDate.substring(0, myDate.length - 5);

console.log(myDateString);
```

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here. Do not redeclare `var`. Read about "hoisting". Furthermore, this is sufficient, `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)`.

Comment: @Gajus for me `Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)` was  not sufficient fails with several dates - wrong by 1 day for 7th June 1979 for instance

Comment: -1 when you use `toISOString()` you are converting the date from the timezone shown into UTC time.  So for example if the web page you are looking at is on GMT-6 and showing a GMT-6 time and your browser is running on a computer that is GMT-5 then when you use `toISOString()` you will now have a UTC time that 5 hours off the webpage instead of 6

Answer (score 7):

```js
function js2Sql(cDate) {
    return cDate.getFullYear()
         + '-'
         + ("0" + (cDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
         + '-'
         + ("0" + cDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

const currentDate = new Date();
const sqlDate = js2Sql(currentDate);

console.log(sqlDate);
```

Answer (score 6):

To convert a JavaScript date to a MySQL one, you can do:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const date = currentDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a typo in the first example, when a day has a length less than 1 it is adding the month instead of the day to the result.

Works great though if you change:

```
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + month;
    }
```

to

```
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
```

Thanks for posting that script.

The corrected function looks like:

```
Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;
function Date_toYMD() {
    var year, month, day;
    year = String(this.getFullYear());
    month = String(this.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    day = String(this.getDate());
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
Object.defineProperties(Date.prototype, {
  date: {
    get: function() {
      return this.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    }
  },
  time: {
    get: function() {
      return this.toTimeString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0];
    }
  },
  datetime: {
    get: function() {
      return this.date + " " + this.time
    }
  }
});

const date = (new Date).datetime
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed this for a filename and with the time in the current timezone.

```
const timezoneOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

const date = (new Date(Date.now() - timezoneOffset))
    .toISOString()
    .substring(0, 19)
    .replace('T', '')       // replace T with a space
    .replace(/ /g, "_")     // replace spaces with an underscore
    .replace(/\:/g, ".");   // replace colons with a dot
```

#### Source

- [convert-javascript-to-date-object-to-mysql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15021796/2492536)
- [javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28149561/2492536)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to say that this is likely the best way of going about it. Just confirmed that it works:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').split('Z')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this handy library for all your date formatting needs: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

Can be!

```
function Date_toYMD(d)
{
    var year, month, day;
    year = String(d.getFullYear());
    month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    day = String(d.getDate());
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// function
getDate = function(dateObj){
    var day = dateObj.getDay() < 9 ? '0'+dateObj.getDay():dateObj.getDay();
    var month = dateObj.getMonth() < 9 ? '0'+dateObj.getMonth():dateObj.getMonth();
    return dateObj.getFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
}

// example usage
console.log(getDate(new Date()));

// with custom date
console.log(getDate(new Date(2012,dateObj.getMonth()-30,dateObj.getDay()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dateTimeToMYSQL(datx) {
    var d = new Date(datx),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = d.getDate().toString(),
      year = d.getFullYear(),
      hours = d.getHours().toString(),
      minutes = d.getMinutes().toString(),
      secs = d.getSeconds().toString();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    if (hours.length < 2) hours = '0' + hours;
    if (minutes.length < 2) minutes = '0' + minutes;
    if (secs.length < 2) secs = '0' + secs;
    return [year, month, day].join('-') + ' ' + [hours, minutes, secs].join(':');
  }
```

Note that you can remove the hours, minutes and seconds and you will have the result as YYYY-MM-DD
The advantage is that the datetime entered in the HTML form remains the same: no transformation into UTC

The result will be (for your example) :

```
dateToMYSQL(datx) {
    var d = new Date(datx),
      month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
      day = d.getDate().toString(),
      year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
  }
```