# Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime

Tags: javascript, mysql

Does anyone know how to convert JS dateTime to MySQL datetime? Also is there a way to add a specific number of minutes to JS datetime and then pass it to MySQL datetime?

Answer (score 436, accepted):

```js
var date;
date = new Date();
date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
    ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
console.log(date);
```

or even shorter:

```js
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Output:

```js
2012-06-22 05:40:06
```

For more advanced use cases, including controlling the timezone, consider using http://momentjs.com/:

```js
require('moment')().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

For a lightweight alternative to [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs), consider https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha

```js
require('fecha').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis before date.getUTCDate, and yes this is better.

Comment: Than an implementation suggest by you.

Comment: I thought that's what you meant. :) Can you explain in what way you think this is nicer?

Comment: @kojiro No unnecessary if conditionals, no redundant padding function, better readability. At the end, it is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: The `toISOString` approach is better for modern browsers. (It's supported in IE9 and above.) FWIW, the `toISOString` polyfill described by MDN has a padding function similar to mine. :P

Comment: this will give problem due to timezone

Comment: It throws away the timezone setting, how to keep it?

Comment: Don't use the "UTC" version of the function. The ISO version is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks @Gajus, I was able to use the same idea the other way around, first `.slice(0,19)` then `.replace(' ','T')` in order to convert a MySQL date to a date suitable for Javascript. Cool.

Comment: `toISOString` support: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Date.prototype.toISOString

Comment: combo it up with this to take care of the timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours

Comment: Just use moment, trust me. (I'm on the internet so I'm right)

Comment: The first `0` of `('00' + date....` will never be included in output since `(date.getAnything().length > 0)` is always `true` ;)

Comment: @MA-Maddin Its there simply for code consistency. Its easier to scan code when some logic is applied consistently.

Comment: @Gajus: replacing all `00` by `0` is still code consistent?! :)

Comment: I am probably not understanding your argument. I am referring to the visual appearance of the code.

Comment: Please add something to highlight even shorter part I just missed that part in a hurry.And got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831930/6517383 same as yours

Comment: @chiliNUT could you give an example of "combo it up with this to take care of the timezone"  I see the slack post on how daylight savings etc, but how would you wrap that into the ISO solution here.  I'm not following.

Comment: Incase anyone was interested... Testing this for Daylight savings it seemed to work just fine

let aa = new Date('March 10, 2018 00:00:00');

let bb = new Date('March 12, 2018 00:00:00');

aa.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
"2018-03-10 07:00:00"
bb.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
"2018-03-12 06:00:00"

Comment: @user1819575 while the linked question is specifically about DST, it also contains good bakground on getting the timezone offset in general. So, assuming your mysql datetime field is set to UTC timezone, I meant that you take your javascript Date instance, then find the timezone offset and add it (and optionally factor in DST), which converts your date to UTC, and then call isostring on that to get a mysql formatted timestamp in UTC

Comment: Full workaround with timezone oneliner!! `var d = new Date(); d.toISOString().split('T')[0]+' '+d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];`

Comment: this gives the correct one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime/60002673#60002673

Comment: Beware, the solution from @PauloRobertoRosa in the comment above doesn't work properly when the timezone day is different than UTC! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390893/1317406) for more information

Comment: I recently had to fix a bug because I didn't read the warnings about how this will cause issues if your timezone is not UTC, learn from me and use `moment` instead.

Answer (score 137):

I think the solution can be less clunky by using method [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), it has a wide browser compatibility.

So your expression will be a one-liner:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

The generated output:

> "2017-06-29 17:54:04"

Comment: Works brilliantly! `new Date(1091040026000).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');`

Comment: Great, only one issue here: the more clunky methods will be getting the hour, day, month (even year) **after** application of the js `Date`'s *time zone offset*.  Whereas yours returns the underlying UTC time in MySQL DATETIME format.  In most cases storing the UTC may be better, and in either case your data table should probably give location info in one field. Alternatively, to convert to local time is pretty easy: use `... - Date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000` (NB also adjusts for Daylight Saving Time where applicable).

Comment: do you need the (dot)slice part?

Answer (score 96):

While JS does possess enough basic tools to do this, it's pretty clunky.

```
/**
 * You first need to create a formatting function to pad numbers to two digits…
 **/
function twoDigits(d) {
    if(0 <= d && d < 10) return "0" + d.toString();
    if(-10 < d && d < 0) return "-0" + (-1*d).toString();
    return d.toString();
}

/**
 * …and then create the method to output the date string as desired.
 * Some people hate using prototypes this way, but if you are going
 * to apply this to more than one Date object, having it as a prototype
 * makes sense.
 **/
Date.prototype.toMysqlFormat = function() {
    return this.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + twoDigits(1 + this.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + twoDigits(this.getUTCDate()) + " " + twoDigits(this.getUTCHours()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCSeconds());
};
```

Comment: How do you call a function like this with a variable?

Comment: @Catfish You mean with a specific date? You use a `Date` object. `new Date().toMysqlFormat()` or `new Date(2014,12,14).toMysqlFormat()` or whatever.

Comment: This answer had its day while JavaScript was old and clunky. If you target a modern browser, I recommend [Gajus' `toISOString` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150727/418413).

Answer (score 22):

**JS time value for MySQL**

```
const DATE_FORMATER = require( 'dateformat' );
const datetime = DATE_FORMATER( new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss" );
```

**OR**

```
const MOMENT = require( 'moment' );
const datetime = MOMENT().format( 'YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.000' );
```

you can send this in params its will work.

Comment: toLocaleString() depends on what the locale is. It may be the same as mysql in some places, but it really isn't a good approach generally

Comment: But, a slight variation of localeString can be helpful - `${d.toLocaleDateString("EN-CA")} ${d.toLocaleTimeString("EN-GB")}`

Comment: Incorrect datetime value: '4/7/2023, 11:09:53 AM'
Doesn't work. I figured it wouldn't, but I was curious because 19 people updooted you.

Comment: you can use dateformate or moment library. i personally use moment

Answer (score 14):

For arbitrary date string,

```js
// Your default date object  
var starttime = new Date();
// Get the iso time (GMT 0 == UTC 0)
var isotime = new Date((new Date(starttime)).toISOString() );
// getTime() is the unix time value, in milliseconds.
// getTimezoneOffset() is UTC time and local time in minutes.
// 60000 = 60*1000 converts getTimezoneOffset() from minutes to milliseconds. 
var fixedtime = new Date(isotime.getTime()-(starttime.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));
// toISOString() is always 24 characters long: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ.
// .slice(0, 19) removes the last 5 chars, ".sssZ",which is (UTC offset).
// .replace('T', ' ') removes the pad between the date and time.
var formatedMysqlString = fixedtime.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
console.log( formatedMysqlString );
```

Or a single line solution,

```js
var formatedMysqlString = (new Date ((new Date((new Date(new Date())).toISOString() )).getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000))).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
console.log( formatedMysqlString );
```

This solution also works for Node.js when using Timestamp in mysql.

[@Gajus Kuizinas's first answer seems to modify mozilla's toISOString prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 9):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)+" "+new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest correct way to convert JS Date to SQL datetime format that occur to me is this one. It correctly handles timezone offset.

```js
const toSqlDatetime = (inputDate) => {
    const date = new Date(inputDate)
    const dateWithOffest = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))
    return dateWithOffest
        .toISOString()
        .slice(0, 19)
        .replace('T', ' ')
}

toSqlDatetime(new Date()) // 2019-08-07 11:58:57
toSqlDatetime(new Date('2016-6-23 1:54:16')) // 2016-06-23 01:54:16
```

**Beware that [@Paulo Roberto answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561530/5240190) will produce incorrect results at the turn on new day (i can't leave comments). For example**:

```js
var d = new Date('2016-6-23 1:54:16'),
    finalDate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0]+' '+d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
console.log(finalDate); // 2016-06-22 01:54:16
```

We've got 22 June instead of 23!

Answer (score 7):

I am surprised that no one mention the Swedish date time format for javascript yet.
the BCP 47 language tag for the Swedish language is sv-SE that you can use for the `new Date` "locale" parameter.
I am not saying it is a good practice, but it works.

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString([['sv-SE']])) //2022-09-10 17:02:39
```

Comment: Also work with Lithuania: `new Date().toLocaleString('lt-LT')`. My two favorite countries as a developer!

Answer (score 5):

**The short version:**

```js
// JavaScript timestamps need to be converted to UTC time to match MySQL

// MySQL formatted UTC timestamp +30 minutes
let d = new Date()
let mySqlTimestamp = new Date(
  d.getFullYear(),
  d.getMonth(),
  d.getDate(),
  d.getHours(),
  (d.getMinutes() + 30), // add 30 minutes
  d.getSeconds(),
  d.getMilliseconds()
).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')

console.log("MySQL formatted UTC timestamp: " + mySqlTimestamp)
```

**UTC time is generally the best option** for storing timestamps in MySQL. If you don't have root access, then run `set time_zone = '+00:00'` at the start of your connection.

**Display a timestamp in a specific time zone** in MySQL with the method convert_tz.

```
select convert_tz(now(), 'SYSTEM', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

**JavaScript timestamps are based on your device's clock** and include the time zone. Before sending any timestamps generated from JavaScript, you should convert them to UTC time. JavaScript has a method called toISOString() which formats a JavaScript timestamp to look similar to MySQL timestamp and converts the timestamp to UTC time. The final cleanup takes place with slice and replace.

```
let timestmap = new Date()
timestmap.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
```

**Long version** to show what is happening:

```js
// JavaScript timestamps need to be converted to UTC time to match MySQL

// local timezone provided by user's device
let d = new Date()
console.log("JavaScript timestamp: " + d.toLocaleString())

// add 30 minutes
let add30Minutes = new Date(
  d.getFullYear(),
  d.getMonth(),
  d.getDate(),
  d.getHours(),
  (d.getMinutes() + 30), // add 30 minutes
  d.getSeconds(),
  d.getMilliseconds()
)
console.log("Add 30 mins: " + add30Minutes.toLocaleString())

// ISO formatted UTC timestamp
// timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z"
let isoString = add30Minutes.toISOString()
console.log("ISO formatted UTC timestamp: " + isoString)

// MySQL formatted UTC timestamp: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
let mySqlTimestamp = isoString.slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
console.log("MySQL formatted UTC timestamp: " + mySqlTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is by far the easiest way I can think of

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ")
```

Comment: this works for my in mysql 7

Comment: would this work as well?   `new Date().toISOString().replace("T", " ")`  -- do you really need the (dot)slice?

Answer (score 4):

The venerable [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library has a formatting routine (it overrides ".toString()").  You could also do one yourself pretty easily because the "Date" methods give you all the numbers you need.

Answer (score 3):

Full workaround (to mantain the timezone) using @Gajus answer concept:

```
var d = new Date(),
    finalDate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0]+' '+d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
console.log(finalDate); //2018-09-28 16:19:34 --example output
```

Comment: This only maintains timezone on the time, not on the date.

Answer (score 2):

I have given simple JavaScript date format examples please check the bellow code

```
var data = new Date($.now()); // without jquery remove this $.now()
console.log(data)// Thu Jun 23 2016 15:48:24 GMT+0530 (IST)

var d = new Date,
    dformat = [d.getFullYear() ,d.getMonth()+1,
               d.getDate()
               ].join('-')+' '+
              [d.getHours(),
               d.getMinutes(),
               d.getSeconds()].join(':');

console.log(dformat) //2016-6-23 15:54:16
```

Using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');

console.log(date) // 2016-06-23 15:59:08
```

Example please check https://jsfiddle.net/sjy3vjwm/2/

Comment: I just tried your first code with vanilla javascript and it gives me this result: 2018-4-20 15:11:23. You are not padding the numbers with a leading "0". Also, I don't know about momentjs but don't you have to put "HH" for hour so that it pads it? Maybe that's why you got down voted? (itwasntme)

Answer (score 2):

```
var _t = new Date();
```

if you want UTC format simply

```
_t.toLocaleString('indian', { timeZone: 'UTC' }).replace(/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+), (\w+)/, '$3-$2-$1 $4');
```

or

```
_t.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

and if want in specific timezone then

```
_t.toLocaleString('indian', { timeZone: 'asia/kolkata' }).replace(/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+), (\w+)/, '$3-$2-$1 $4');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `toJSON()` date function as below:

```js
var sqlDatetime = new Date(new Date().getTime() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toJSON().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
console.log(sqlDatetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Datetime in a different time zone

This uses @Gayus solution using the format outputted from `toISOString()`  but it adjusts the minutes to account for the time zone.
Final format: `2022-03-01 13:32:51`

```js
let ts = new Date();
ts.setMinutes(ts.getMinutes() - ts.getTimezoneOffset());
console.log(ts.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is send a timestamp to MySQL and let it do the conversion. Javascript uses timestamps in milliseconds whereas MySQL expects them to be in seconds - so a division by 1000 is needed:

```
// Current date / time as a timestamp:
let jsTimestamp = Date.now();

// **OR** a specific date / time as a timestamp:
jsTimestamp = new Date("2020-11-17 16:34:59").getTime();

// Adding 30 minutes (to answer the second part of the question):
jsTimestamp += 30 * 1000;

// Example query converting Javascript timestamp into a MySQL date
let sql = 'SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(' + jsTimestamp + ' / 1000) AS mysql_date_time';
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a function to return the sql timestamp format in javascript form a selective timezone

```html
<script>
console.log(getTimestamp("Europe/Amsterdam")); // Europe/Amsterdam
console.log(getTimestamp()); // UTC

function getTimestamp(timezone) {
  if (timezone) { 
  var dateObject = new Date().toLocaleString("nl-NL", { // it will parse with the timeZone element, not this one
    timeZone: timezone, // timezone eg "Europe/Amsterdam" or "UTC"
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
    year: "numeric",

    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
  });

  let [dateRaw, timeRaw] = dateObject.split(" ");
  let [day, month, year] = dateRaw.split("-");
  var timestamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + timeRaw;
  }else{
  // UTC from @Gajus, 95% faster then the above
  timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ");
  }
  return timestamp; // YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) then the functionality can be achived easily using [format](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format) function.

```
const format = require("date-fns/format");
const date = new Date();

const formattedDate = format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way -

`new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace("T", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this long time and it's very helpful for me, use as you like

```
Date.prototype.date=function() {
    return this.getFullYear()+'-'+String(this.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0')+'-'+String(this.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
}

Date.prototype.time=function() {
    return String(this.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')+':'+String(this.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')+':'+String(this.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0')
}

Date.prototype.dateTime=function() {
    return this.getFullYear()+'-'+String(this.getMonth()+1).padStart(2, '0')+'-'+String(this.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')+' '+String(this.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')+':'+String(this.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')+':'+String(this.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0')
}

Date.prototype.addTime=function(time) {
    var time=time.split(":")
    var rd=new Date(this.setHours(this.getHours()+parseInt(time[0])))
    rd=new Date(rd.setMinutes(rd.getMinutes()+parseInt(time[1])))
    return new Date(rd.setSeconds(rd.getSeconds()+parseInt(time[2])))
}

Date.prototype.addDate=function(time) {
    var time=time.split("-")
    var rd=new Date(this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear()+parseInt(time[0])))
    rd=new Date(rd.setMonth(rd.getMonth()+parseInt(time[1])))
    return new Date(rd.setDate(rd.getDate()+parseInt(time[2])))
}

Date.prototype.subDate=function(time) {
    var time=time.split("-")
    var rd=new Date(this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear()-parseInt(time[0])))
    rd=new Date(rd.setMonth(rd.getMonth()-parseInt(time[1])))
    return new Date(rd.setDate(rd.getDate()-parseInt(time[2])))
}
```

and then just:

```
new Date().date()
```

which returns current date in 'MySQL format'

for add time is

```
new Date().addTime('0:30:0')
```

which will add 30 minutes.... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Solution built on the basis of other answers, while maintaining the timezone and leading zeros:

```
var d = new Date;

var date = [
    d.getFullYear(),
    ('00' + d.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2),
    ('00' + d.getDate() + 1).slice(-2)
].join('-');

var time = [
    ('00' + d.getHours()).slice(-2),
    ('00' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
    ('00' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
].join(':');

var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
console.log(dateTime) // 2021-01-41 13:06:01
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: just Replace the T.
Format that I have from my <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"   is :
"2021-02-10T18:18"

So just replace the T, and it would look like this: "2021-02-10 18:18" SQL will eat that.

Here is my function:

var CreatedTime = document.getElementById("example-datetime-local-input").value;

var newTime = CreatedTime.replace("T", " ");

Reference:
[https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-replace-character-inside-a-string-in-javascript.php#:~:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20JavaScript%20replace,the%20global%20(%20g%20)%20modifier](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-replace-character-inside-a-string-in-javascript.php#:%7E:text=Answer%3A%20Use%20the%20JavaScript%20replace,the%20global%20(%20g%20)%20modifier).

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=javascript-replace-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

What about this one taking account the timezone offset?

```js
const getTimestamp = (date = false) => {
  const d = ! date ? new Date() : new Date(date);

  return new Date(d - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000).toJSON().replace('T', ' ').split('.')[0];
}

console.log(getTimestamp());
console.log(getTimestamp('2016-6-23 1:54:16'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dateToSqlDate = (date) => date.toISOString().slice(0, -5).replace('T', ' ')

console.log(dateToSqlDate(new Date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for me:

```
function DateToSql(d: Date): string {
    let dt: Date = new Date(d.getTime());
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() - dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return dt.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for external libraries or string manipulation.

Create js date object (I use datepicker format as an example) and
convert it to Swedish locals, which is the same format that mysql uses:

```
var local_time ="Fri Oct 06 2023 01:01:25 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)";

const d = new Date(local_time);      // d=2023-10-05T22:01:25.000Z
today = d.toLocaleString('sv-SE');   // 2023-10-06 01:01:25
```

And then use MYSQL function to convert time zone to mysql UTC time

```
select convert_tz('2023-10-06 01:01:25','+03:00', 'SYSTEM') // 2023-10-05 22:01:25
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and Short way to store DateTime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) into MySQL Database

```
const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState('');

setDateTime(new Date(YOUR_DATETIME).toLocaleString('sv-SE')); // Any Date formate into this formate (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

// On submit or Something conditions

axios.post('url',dateTime).then((res)=>{});
```