# date format in node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql database,in that i have a field by name `request_date`. The type of the field is time stamp and the data stored in this field has the format `2012-05-16 14:59:18`.
But when I retrieve the same data by Node.JS, the data is displayed in the browser as

```
Fri Jun 08 2012 15:16:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Why this format change is happening?

I have written this query:

```
SELECT
biz_registration.reqid,biz_registration.request_date,biz_registration.req_status,biz_registration.annual_cost,biz_registration.rid,biz_contact.first_name,biz_contact.last_name
FROM biz_registration
INNER JOIN biz_contact ON biz_registration.reqid=biz_contact.reqid
ORDER BY biz_registration.request_date
DESC limit '+start+','+mlimit+''
```

the html code i am using is,

```
options +='<div class="column" style="background-color: #E1E1E1;width:         100px;">'+result.reqid+'</div>';
options +='<div class="column" style="background-color: #E1E1E1;width: 160px;">'+result.request_date+'</div>';
```

Comment: How are you converting the date from the query into a `Date` object in Node.JS? How are you displaying the date in HTML? The query is probably fine, this is HTML formatting or `Date` object creation issue.

Comment: Please post the code that you use to convert the date into a js Date object (if you do) and the code that generates the html.  In js Date-objects the months start at 0. January is month 0, June is is month 5.

Comment: What library are you using for MySQL - Node.JS connection?

Comment: i am not doing any date object conversion.can anyone help me in doing it.thanks in advance

Comment: thank u to all who gave the hints.

Answer (score 34):

I was having the same problem, this fixed my problem:

You need to 'force' your mysql connection to format it immediately, add this into your config(connection details):

```
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root'
// ....
dateStrings: 'date'
```

---

Note that in many cases

```
dateStrings: true
```

rather than `'date'`

seems to be the needed solution.

Comment: Could you please explain more your solution?

Comment: I had a customer database with some orders and when I wanted to display Date of the order I would get a very long date format
(example from first post)

Then I was trying to find a simple solution so I can just display the actual date 'MM/dd/YYYY' and with the code from above it worked perfectly. I found that example on some other site, can't remember right now.

This is how it looks at me right now:

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database',
  dateStrings: 'date'
});

Comment: All the options from the node-mysql docs: dateStrings: Force date types (TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE) to be returned as strings rather then inflated into JavaScript Date objects. (Default: false) -- I was looking for DATETIME myself

Answer (score 23):

This config resolve mine, according to 
[node-mysql doc](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

```js
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  dateStrings:true,
  database: "mydb"
```

Answer (score 8):

i got this working by requiring the library or module called date format.
first we have to install date format package using

> npm install dateformat

then u can require it in ur coding. 
then u can create the object of retrieved data as

> var day=dateFormat(result.request_date, "yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss");

and print it.

Comment: Please note that the correct format for mysql is:  "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime/49555117#49555117) :

```
var datetme = new Date().toLocaleString();
```

OR

```
const DATE_FORMATER = require( 'dateformat' );
var datetme = DATE_FORMATER( new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss" );
```

Answer (score 2):

What you see, is simply the default javascript date formatting. If you want it formatted differently, you can use the methods:

```
getDate(): Returns the date
getMonth(): Returns the month
getFullYear(): Returns the year
```

on the date object, and combine the results with / or - or : to get the format you want.

Have a look at: http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't get to format your date with the `yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss` (database format) just by using `new Date().toLocaleString` or `new Date().toISOString()`.

To achieve this we need to add the dateformat package

`npm install dateformat`

Then we use

`const dateFormat = require ('dateformat');`

So to assign a date you can use dateFormat

`var created_at = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd h:MM:ss');`