# How to change SQL DATE format to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: mysql, sql, dataformat

I have a column named "start_date" with Datatype "DATE".
On my DB table, it shows as "YYYY-MM-DD" format but when I extract Data from my project (using node.js) I get the result as "YYYY-MM-DDT22:00:00.000Z".
How can I change the format to "YYYY-MM-DD" ?
I tried FORMAT(start_date, "yyyy-MM-dd") but didn't work...

I understand that we can normally use moment to change the format from a client side like moment(start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") but I'm trying to do it from Server-side.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187961/date-format-in-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` function to format the date.

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Since the format doesn't change, all it does is casting to string. So this should also work: `cast(start_date as char)` or `concat(start_date)`.