# Saving data from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, save

I'm trying to save data from jquery but it doesn't work so I need your help!
I'm using CakePHP 2.3. So this is my jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/test/reservations/save',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {reservation_time_from : calEvent.start, reservation_time_to: calEvent.end, user_id : "1", laboratory_id : "1"},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("saved")
    }
});
```

Controller

```
 public function save() {
    if ($this->data != null) {
        $this->Reservation->save($this->request->data);
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Maybe it doesn't work because of date format in jQuery (Mon Aug 26 2013 11:00:00 GMT+0200)?

Comment: Column name date should be DATETIME, check it what u have set,and before saving the data check the data is coming fine, and after save put false, $this->Reservation->save($this->request->data,false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not correctly formatted for passing it to `Model::save()`. Please refer to the documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

It should be in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

So the object passed to the AJAX calls `data` property should look like this:

```
{ModelName: {fieldname1: 1, fieldname2: 2}}
```

In your case that would be:

```
{Reservation: {reservation_time_from: calEvent.start, reservation_time_to: calEvent.end, user_id: 1, laboratory_id: 1}}
```

Checking for a POST request instead of `data` being `null` *might* also be a good idea, ie:

```
if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Reservation->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Also check if you are using the [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) which may [blackhole](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks) the request.

And last but not least, check for the date format you've already mentioned, in case validation is involved this might be a problem too, at least it's a problem in case the table column expects a different format. So, format the date properly if necessary, see [Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime) or http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/ in case you are using [FullCalender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) (just guessing by your event/property names).

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes it is validation of datetime. If i comment validation for fields reservation_time_from and reservation_time_to it saves data to database but with date 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: So you have to format the date properly, I've added two links to some examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {reservation_time_from : calEvent.start, reservation_time_to: calEvent.end, user_id : "1", laboratory_id : "1"},
```

is not valid json.

You need double quotes on your key to be considered valid.

If reservation_time_from is a variable, then you should create an object literal and add it in the following way:

```
myDataObject = {};
myDataObject[reservation_time_from] = calEvent.Start;
```

Once you have built your json object, you can then pass it in as the value for the data key.

Comment: thank you for your response but still not working I m assuming there is problem with date format

Comment: post more code.  also, what are you getting back in response?  console.log(data) so you can see what's comeing back.  error: function(error){} as well so you can see if there are errors.  How are you converting $_POST to data on server?  these would help.  :)

Comment: @carter The `data` property doesn't expect a JSON string, it expects a plain string (a query string in the default configuration), or an key/value object or array.