# Javascript date to sql date object

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that takes a Javascript date object and then puts it in an object type that is recognized by both SQL Server and Oracle database types.

The issue is that I'm using webservices. So it has to be a string, not an actual passed parameter. Here's what I mean:

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

var webServicesQueryWhereClause = 'readDate BETWEEN '+firstDayOfMonth+' AND '+lastDayOfMonth;
```

Except `firstDayOfMonth` and `lastDayOfMonth` are surrounded by something like `to_date()` to actually put them in a date format that the databases can read. For example:

```
var webServicesQueryWhereClause = 'readDate BETWEEN to_date('+firstDayOfMonth+') AND to_date('+lastDayOfMonth+') ';
```

What should I use to put those dates in a form that can be read by both SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: All SQL databases can read the ISO date format unambiguously: ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") `firstDayOfMonth.toISOString()` should do the trick.

Comment: How is this being executed? Which library are you using? It's generally best to leave it up to the DB to decide how to translate a date object to a recognised format (however, that may not be possible in your case).

Comment: I'd suggest building the query string in your web service layer, unless this is node.js code. If you use asp.net, take a look at:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/

Comment: @James I'm using the atmosphere library and javax.jws server side to handle the web services.

Comment: @guiomie That's not an option. This query string being run from an app created with Sencha.

Comment: @Graham For the future reference,
`moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Have you tried the solutions presented here:

[Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime)

The title should be called

"Convert JS date to SQL DateTime"

I happened to need to do the same thing as you just now and I ran across this after your question.

This is from the other post by Gajus Kuizinas for those who want the answers on this page:

```
var pad = function(num) { return ('00'+num).slice(-2) };
var date;
date = new Date();
date = date.getUTCFullYear()         + '-' +
        pad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1)  + '-' +
        pad(date.getUTCDate())       + ' ' +
        pad(date.getUTCHours())      + ':' +
        pad(date.getUTCMinutes())    + ':' +
        pad(date.getUTCSeconds());
```

---

or

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

The first one worked for me. I had a reference problem with the toISOString as well although I would prefer the one liner. Can anyone clarify how to use it and know the limitations on where one can reference it?
Good luck!

Comment: `toISOString` support is IE9+ http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Date.prototype.toISOString

Comment: question was on MS SQL  ( T-sql)   not mysql   :/

Comment: The first one worked for me, but it has a typo: for each "pad" there must be a closing of the function call, ie one ")".

Comment: Careful with `toISOString`: a same date can return different results according to your timezone and day time! Example: now is june 29 at 22:58 (UTC+2) and `new Date(2023, 5, 29).toISOString()` is returning `2023-06-28T22:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 7):

using MomentJs it will be pretty easy.

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 5):

In my case I was trying to get a TIMESTAMP and store it to a variable so I can pass that array inside a SQL query(Row insertion)

The following worked for me quite well.

```
var created_at = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Comment: There's already a answer with this exact snipet

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I found a bit shorter approach - tested on MSSQL and Postgres

```
const date = (new Date()).toLocaleString("en-US")
```

> Enjoy!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The return value is "6/30/2021, 2:39:16 PM" while It needs to be of type "2021-06-30 2:39:16 PM".

Answer (score 2):

Slice off the `.sssZ` (milliseconds and Z UTC timezone) and replace the `T` with a space:

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -5).replace('T', ' ')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
const datetimeSQL = new Date().toISOString().split('T').join(' ').split('Z').join('');
// return '2022-09-02 19:54:17.028'
```

Comment: I think new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/Z/, '') would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @timkay, i'll try it the next time :+1

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is one country in the world that is sql friendly:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('lt-LT'));
// 2023-12-18 10:48:55
```

Hurray for Lithuania!