# How to fetch date from date function in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, date

I need the current date so I am writing a below code

```
dateCreated = new Date();
```

which returns **Thu Dec 05 2013 12:57:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**.

But when I am trying to store it into database it is showing an error

I am using `DateTime` datatype to store date in SQL Server 2012 database

I even tried using Date datatype but it is showing me error.

Is there any way to do this?

I just want to store date

Comment: What error it is showing and what you want to achieve??

Comment: `i am trying to store it into database`: how ?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime

Comment: @Trupti In which format you want to store date in database..? Could you please provide the format?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in a format that SQL understands. It doesn't understand the string Thu Dec 05 2013 12:57:48 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) just format it how SQL likes it.

e.g. YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: perhaps the Op doesn't know "how sql likes it" ;)

Comment: Or just: `yyyyMMdd`. (to include time: `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`)

Comment: OP wanted the date though. Time was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Format the date according your need

```
function getDate() {  
    TDate = new Date(); 
    CurYear = TDate.getYear();
    CurMonth = TDate.getMonth();
    CurDay = TDate.getDate();
    CurHour = TDate.getHours(); 
    CurMins = TDate.getMinutes(); 
    CurSecs = TDate.getSeconds();

    CurDay = ((CurDay < 10) ? '-0' : '-') + CurDay;
    CurMins = ((CurMins < 10) ? ':0' : ':') + CurMins;
    CurSecs = ((CurSecs < 10) ? ':0' : ':') + CurSecs;

    TheDate = '';
    TheDate += ((CurYear%1900)+1900) + '-';
    TheDate += CurMonth;
    TheDate += CurDay + ' ';
    TheDate += CurHour;
    TheDate += CurMins;
    TheDate += CurSecs;
    return TheDate;
}

alert(getDate()); //YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```