# Using Node.js (Express) and mySQL to INSERT for a TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Just trying to do some simple messaging here:

```
   var post = {
        sender_username : sender_username,
        recipient_username : recipient_username, 
        message_no : 1,
        content : content, 
        time : ***CURRENT TIMESTAMP***, 
        read : 0
    };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO message SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(post); 
        }
    });
```

What's the simplest way to stick the date and time in there that is valid for the TIMESTAMP type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native JS way can be found in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime).

Personally, I use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for anything that deals with dates.

```
moment().utc().format('hh:mm:ss')
```

NOTE: I got confused with your question. You asked for "CURRENT_TIME" but your format is TIMESTAMP. MySQL's TIME and TIMESTAMP types are different. TIMESTAMP contains both the date and time and the default value function for that is "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". I'm assuming you're referring to the TIME type.

Comment: I happened to already be using moment for birthdays, so this is awesome. Node.js has some great modules! (EDIT: I actually meant the TIMESTAMP type. I'll clear that up in my post.)

Answer (score 24):

You can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this purpose:

**Date.now** returns current timestamp in millisecond and moment also works with milliseconds.

```
var mysqlTimestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Since the question is for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{time: new Date(GMTtimeString).toLocaleString()}` where `GMTtimeString` sent from front-end.