# Passing &referrer to new page

Tags: javascript, php, analytics, referrer

First time posting, new web designer here.  I'm creating a new landing page for a university (https://uab.edu/give/now/evergive). In the past, when we've created pages, we use &referrer.  The new page I've created acts as a landing page, so we'd attach the referrer to the end and end up with a URL like this : https://www.uab.edu/give/now/evergive?referrer=AFEM1  Trouble is, it doesn't pass the referrer to the next page when you select a fund.  I don't have a way to touch the form (it's being controlled by another department), so how can I pass the referrer value to the second page?

---EDIT!---

I realize I failed to mention the &referrer in question comes from social & email links (we're getting their analytics set up.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Comment: If you need it to be passed around all pages, you probably wanna set a cookie instead, or you have to write a lot of code to make sure your links add that query parameter

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about just getting the HTTP `referer` header? For example, when I visit a link, my browser sends the following HTTP headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: { Redacted }
```

See the `referer` header?

You can get this in PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and JS `document.referrer`.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can't be relied upon, read why http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: A user can copy the link and remove `?refer` anyway. You will never get 100% reliability.