# convert json datetime format (2018-01-05T22:58:23.937 ... "T" within datetime-value to be stored in sql database)

Tags: php, datetime

how to convert a date/time value received by "json decoding"

> 2018-01-05T22:58:23.937  (value of $TimeStamp)

to insert into a SQL-Database-Field type of **DATETIME**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO database (date1,...) VALUES ($ddate1, ...)
```

this won't work:

```
$ddate1 = date_format(new datetime($TimeStamp), 'y.m.d H:i:s');
```

removing 'T' won't work either

```
$ddate1 = strtr($TimeStamp,"T"," "); 
$ddate1 = date_format(new datetime($ddate1), 'y.m.d H:i:s');
```

**UPDATE 6.01.2018**

```
$now = date("y.m.d H:i:s"); $TimeStamp = $fgc['result'][$i]["TimeStamp"];  // (result of json)

echo "OK:" .$now .'<br />'; 
echo "nOK: (format of source) sorce" .$TimeStamp .'<br />';
$dt1 = date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime($Timestamp)); echo "convert:" .$dt1 .'<br />';
$dt2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Timestamp)); echo "convert:" .$dt2 .'<br />';
```

Result:

```
OK:

18.01.06 12:48:39

(sample stored correcrtly in database)

nOK: (format of source) sorce2018-01-06T11:48:40.207

convert:1970.01.01 01:00:00

convert:1970-01-01
```

thanks for any hints

Stefan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime)

Comment: You need to quote the date in the INSERT statement, as it will be passed as a string literal: `"INSERT INTO database (date1,...) VALUES ('$ddate1', ...)`.

Comment: it is quoted  $query = "INSERT INTO kurse ( Zeitstempel,  DatumUpdate, ... ) VALUES   ( '$now',  '$dt1', ...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** (confirmed in [Stefan S.'s answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/48127768) below.

Comment: yes, thanks, can be closed ... do I ave to close the question?
I can't see how/where?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$date = '2018-01-05T22:58:23.937';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); // 2018-01-05
```

Alternatively, you can use `OOP` style `DateTime` class as follows:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2018-01-05T22:58:23.937');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thank you ... problem solved partly .. at least new record is generated but value in database is set to: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 $dt = date('y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime($dt)); also is set to 0000-.... i guess I am close to the solution ...

Comment: Mh ok... have you made some tests to see what is the current PHP time offset (`date_default_timezone_get`) and the current MySQL time offset? What is your MySQL defaut date format?

Comment: echo "OK:" .$now .'<br />';
       
    echo "nOK: (format of source) sorce" .$TimeStamp .'<br />';
    
    $dt1 = date('Y.m.d H:i:s', strtotime($Timestamp));
    echo "convert:" .$dt1 .'<br />';
    
    $dt2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Timestamp));
    echo "convert:" .$dt2 .'<br />';

Answer (score 0):

problem solved (just the same coding as in my first post ... must have been an different error ... sorry!)

> $TimeStamp      = $fgc['result'][$i]["TimeStamp"];

converted by

> $DatumUpdate    = date_format(new datetime($TimeStamp ), 'y.m.d
>   H:i:s');

stored correctly in database

Answer (score 0):

make a function like blew what u need im not coded just exple it u need make it wt u need..

```
    function shortDu($t) {
$sam = str_replace('PT','',$t);
$sam = str_replace('H',':',$sam);
$sam = str_replace('M',':',$sam);
$sam = str_replace('S','',$sam);
return $sam;}
```

apply this shortDu(); on your current value then get perfect result then input in db