# How to convert seconds to datetime format?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have this variable `var resetPasswordExpires = 1524133033085;` and I want to convert seconds to datetime format to update database sql column. 
I did this

```
 var d = new Date();
 d.toString(resetPasswordExpires);
```

and i take d =  Thu Apr 19 2018 12:21:02 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight
 Time) and of course canot save column to database.
Database column format is DATETIME

query :

```
UPDATE User SET resetPasswordToken = 
c2d313284f6de68cc1f18e3c45b0ea2c720220f0, resetPasswordExpires = Thu Apr 19 
2018 12:21:02 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time) WHERE UserID = 21;
```

Comment: Is that the number of seconds from 1900-01-01?

Comment: @MJH Yes, check online using an epoch calculator.

Comment: I *suspect* that what you actually have in hand is the number of *milliseconds* since 1970-01-01. So the first thing I'd suggest is that you actually clear up what that number is *meant* to be/represent.

Comment: Yes, the number is the result of var resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; I want to save this variable in database

Comment: Isnt this more a C# question on how to format your datetime value you get outputted from your C# app?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to `DATEADD` the number of seconds in your value to the start of the UNIX epoch:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, 1524133033085/1000, '19700101 00:00:00:000');

19.04.2018 10:17:13
```

### Demo

Note that I divide your value by 1000 because it is in milliseconds.

Comment: And/or just add the milliseconds instead of seconds instead of dividing by 1000? There is an ‘ms’ option for ‘dateadd’ if I remember correctly.

Comment: @thomas I wasn't sure of that, and you know how SO is, post quickly or lose.

Comment: I hear ya! Just checked and there is a millisecond, microsecond, and nanosecond option.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is already answered in [Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime). Please validate your requirement.

```
var resetPasswordExpires = 1524133033085;
var d = new Date(1524133033085).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that is exactly i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

TESTED and SOLVED

Convert your timestamp as following

**try in Console**

```
var resetPasswordExpires = 1524133033085;
var d = new Date();
d.toString(resetPasswordExpires);
var passDateToISOString  = d.toISOString();
passDateToISOString
```

**Result in console**

```
"2018-04-19T09:55:14.824Z"
```

then Pass **passDateToISOString** variable value to your sql

for Example ( **try in Sql** )

```
UPDATE User 
SET resetPasswordToken = c2d313284f6de68cc1f18e3c45b0ea2c720220f0, 
resetPasswordExpires = '2018-04-19T09:55:14.824Z' 
WHERE UserID = 21;
```