# How to convert nodejs string To mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, lamp

I am trying to put a date to my mysql database. The column type is date.
the value of orderDate is '2018-04-18' however after putting it into the database it is changed to 1997-00-00 why is that and how can i get the actual value into the database?

This is the function I used: `STR_TO_DATE(${orderDate}, "%Y-%M-%D");`
If I dont use the function I get an error saying 1997 is an invalid date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime/5133807

Comment: Are you using any ORM in. Nodejs?

Comment: `1997-00-00` is indeed an invalid date, maybe you meant to send: `1997-01-01` ?

Comment: @alfasin no I sent 2018-04-18 and it was somehow converted to 1997-00-00