# How to checkin and checkout time data save in mysql using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, time

*How to checkin and checkout time data save in MySQL using jquery?*

.checkin button click to start live time
.checkout button click then stop time 
.And both are save data in MYSQL database...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime

Answer (score 1):

you can make an Ajax call to your server, and if you are using Carbon date library in your Laravel app, then use Carbon::now() to log the current checkin and checkout time.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "user/checkin", success: function(result){
    // to do
  }});
});

$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "user/checkout", success: function(result){
    // to do
  }});
});
```

then at the controller function

```
public function checkin(Request $request) {
  $user = $request->user();

  $user->checkin_in = \Carbon::now();
  $user->save();

}
```

Comment: but how to display live time? till checkin to checkout

Comment: you can use the Date() JS function or use a helper library moment.js [https://momentjs.com/] in Javascript and in php , carbon::now() for current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Copied from here: [Convert JS date time to MySQL datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime)