# Javascript datetime issue - converting to utc

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc

My database value is this

> 2020-03-08 20:44:00

But in javascript. It display

> Mon Mar 09 2020 09:44:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)

Want i want to display on UI

> 2020-03-08 20:44:00

or

> 2020-03-08

Is there a way to remove the timezone and get only the actual value from the database.

Comment: `toISOString` method perhaps? - sorry, no .. `.toUTCString` method

Comment: is the date being fetched from the database using js?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear: the two dates are the same, since they indicate the **same moment in time**. So, if you're talking about how to display the date object as a string, the first comment gives you the adequate solution.

Comment: this didnt work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129624/convert-js-date-time-to-mysql-datetime

Comment: @JenuelGanawed I think whatever library he's using converts the database timestamp to a date object, so this is a question of getting the date string in the same format as the first one.

Comment: for display purpose. i want to display the db value instead of ut converted

Comment: @PaulWhite, can you show us the code, how your fetching the data from the database

Comment: You may want to consider using moment-timezone (js library) if you're working on an app where you will be dealing with timezones often.

Comment: Luxon is another date/timezone library suggestion as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toISOString is not a proper way to get date into DateTime. please follow the below method to get a date from DateTime.

```js
var date = new Date("2020-03-08 20:44:00");
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
var day = date.getDate().toString();
day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
var newDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

console.log("Date plush time - "+date);
console.log("Only Date - "+newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the silently using Date object's `.toString()` method which converts the UTC date (that your database is storing) into a time in the current time zone.

If `date` is the variable that you get from your database, then you can format it like you want it like this:

```js
let dateString = date.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
```

This will take your date, convert it into an ISO string (in the form `2020-01-10T03:09:24.551Z`) and replace the T with a space and everything after the decimal with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
 let d = new Date('2020-03-08 20:44:00');
console.log(`${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1) : d.getMonth() + 1}-${d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + (d.getDate()): d.getDate()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take each part of the date and construct your own format
example:

```
let formatted_date = my_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (my_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + my_date.getDate()
```

in this example: my_date hold the date you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use a library, use moment.js

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

```
moment("2020-03-08 20:44:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

or

```
moment(new Date("2020-03-08 20:44:00")).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

It can even change the time to utc

https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

```
moment.utc("2020-03-08 20:44:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Subtract your timezone offset milliseconds.

```js
var dt = new Date('2020-03-08 20:44:00');
dt = new Date(dt.getTime()-dt.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);
console.log(dt.toUTCString());
var mo = dt.getUTCMonth()+1, d = dt.getUTCDate(), h = dt.getUTCHours();
var m = dt.getUTCMinutes(), s = dt.getUTCSeconds();
if(mo < 10)mo = '0'+mo;
if(d < 10)d = '0'+d;
if(h < 10)h = '0'+h;
if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
if(s < 10)s = '0'+s;
console.log(dt.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+mo+'-'+d+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s);
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, he wants to output the first value from the database exactly.