# javascript toISOString() ignores timezone offset

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone-offset

I am trying to convert Twitter datetime to a local iso-string (for prettyDate) now for 2 days. I'm just not getting the local time right..

im using the following function:

```
function getLocalISOTime(twDate) {
    var d = new Date(twDate);
    var utcd = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(),
        d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds(), d.getMilliseconds());

    // obtain local UTC offset and convert to msec
    localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var newdate = new Date(utcd + localOffset);
    return newdate.toISOString().replace(".000", "");
}
```

in newdate everything is ok but the toISOString() throws it back to the original time again...
Can anybody help me get the local time in iso from the Twitterdate formatted as:
Thu, 31 May 2012 08:33:41 +0000

Comment: The format you describe at the end is not the [ISO-8601E](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf) format (see also [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). You can achieve the format you want quite easily; it's very close to what you get with `dateObj.toString()`. Try playing with that.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up with this:                                               var d = new Date(twDate);
    return new Date(d.toISOString().replace("Z", "-02:00")).toISOString().replace(".000", "");     Not the prettiest solution but works for my timezone.

Comment: @Bergi : Paradoxically, an older question cannot be a duplicate of a newer one ;)

Comment: Here is a method without any manual timezone settings:
var now = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
  var timeToSet = now.toISOString().slice(0,16);
  
  var elem = document.getElementById("eventdate");
  elem.value = timeToSet;
  elem.min = timeToSet;

Answer (score 452, accepted):

`moment.js` is great but sometimes you don't want to pull a large number of dependencies for simple things.

The following works as well:

```js
    var tzoffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
    var localISOTime = (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0, -1);
    
    console.log(localISOTime)  // => '2015-01-26T06:40:36.181'
```

The `slice(0, -1)` gets rid of the trailing `Z` which represents Zulu timezone and can be replaced by your own.

Comment: short and simple - brilliant! To make it even more human readable I put .toISOString().slice(0,-5).replace("T", " "); at the end of your solution.

Comment: Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").

Comment: Excellent, thanks.
Here it is, as a function that takes an optional date parameter:
function localISOTime(d) {
    if (!d) d = new Date()
    var tzoffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
    return (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)).toISOString().slice(0, -1);
}

Comment: Why the "-" (now-tzoffset)?

Comment: @NicoDurand your function has a bug, it always returns the current Date. Should be "d - tzoffset"

Comment: Your solution it does not show your local time. It trick the date thinking your UTC date is your local date. You should not change your date your should add your timezone offset

Comment: @MarioShtika We all know it is tricky because `Date` object doesn't provide a `toLocalISOString`. Then what's the correct way? Show us.

Comment: See this answer for a more detailed explanation of each operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643788/1412157

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be correct for all space and time?

Comment: Be careful using `.getTimezoneOffset()`, whatever date you provide (from different timezones) it will always resolve to your local timezone offset.

Example: 

`const date1 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+07:00');`
`const date2 = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT-02:00');`

`console.log(date1.getTimezoneOffset() === date2.getTimezoneOffset()); // true`

[source MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset#description)

Answer (score 172):

My solution without using `moment` is to convert it to a timestamp, add the timezone offset, then convert back to a date object, and then run the `toISOString()`

```
var date = new Date(); // Or the date you'd like converted.
var isoDateTime = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString();
```

Comment: I like this approach.  You example doesn't work as-is because you haven't defined date.  If you prepend var date = new Date(); to your example, it works.

Comment: it works! but I don't understand why you multiply by 60000 ? :s

Comment: Beautiful and very simple. Thank you. Just a note: it does keep "Z" at the end of the string, which is technically wrong, but easy to edit out.

Comment: @betoharres that is to transform the time zone offset to milliseconds, which is what getTime is in.

Comment: @Dustin Silk so the solution proposed by you convert the datetime in local iso. Is there any way using which I can show the same date whether the user opens the app in usa, Europe or for say India. I am really struggling with it. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Your solution gives me `2020-01-17T11:24:15.109Z`. I like this approach better https://stackoverflow.com/a/17415677/588759 which shows for me correct zone `2020-01-17T11:25:26+01:00` with this patch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415579/how-to-iso-8601-format-a-date-with-timezone-offset-in-javascript/17415677#comment78688226_17415677

Answer (score 12):

moment.js FTW!!!

Just convert your date to a moment and manipulate it however you please:

```
var d = new Date(twDate);
var m = moment(d).format();
console.log(m);
// example output:
// 2016-01-08T00:00:00-06:00
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: That's not a proper answer... Can you give the right answer using Moment.js ? If that's a real answer, I can answer everytime "x86 FTW !!! https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf " and say good luck...

Comment: [*When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: I logged in after many years offline just to note that this answer allow to format Date in order for a .NET API to receive a date with the TimeZone and deserialize it properly. It's not that bad to have moment.js in a js project, knowing how much the Date API from ECMAScript lacks of functionalities.

Comment: I logged in after many years offline just to note that the solution offered in the answer allows to serialize a local hour properly in ISO8601. moment.js exists because the Date API from ECMAScript sucks.

Answer (score 12):

Using `moment.js`, you can use `keepOffset` parameter of `toISOString`:

`toISOString(keepOffset?: boolean): string;`

`moment().toISOString(true)`

Comment: It is alarming how much better this answer is compared to all the other answers. Thank you.

Comment: FYI moment.js is no longer recommended by the moment.js team: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 6):

This date function below achieves the desired effect without an additional script library. Basically it's just a simple date component concatenation in the right format, and augmenting of the Date object's prototype.

```
 Date.prototype.dateToISO8601String  = function() {
    var padDigits = function padDigits(number, digits) {
        return Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
    }
    var offsetMinutes = this.getTimezoneOffset();
    var offsetHours = offsetMinutes / 60;
    var offset= "Z";    
    if (offsetHours < 0)
      offset = "-" + padDigits(offsetHours.replace("-","") + "00",4);
    else if (offsetHours > 0) 
      offset = "+" + padDigits(offsetHours  + "00", 4);

    return this.getFullYear() 
            + "-" + padDigits((this.getUTCMonth()+1),2) 
            + "-" + padDigits(this.getUTCDate(),2) 
            + "T" 
            + padDigits(this.getUTCHours(),2)
            + ":" + padDigits(this.getUTCMinutes(),2)
            + ":" + padDigits(this.getUTCSeconds(),2)
            + "." + padDigits(this.getUTCMilliseconds(),2)
            + offset;

}

Date.dateFromISO8601 = function(isoDateString) {
      var parts = isoDateString.match(/\d+/g);
      var isoTime = Date.UTC(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
      var isoDate = new Date(isoTime);
      return isoDate;       
}

function test() {
    var dIn = new Date();
    var isoDateString = dIn.dateToISO8601String();
    var dOut = Date.dateFromISO8601(isoDateString);
    var dInStr = dIn.toUTCString();
    var dOutStr = dOut.toUTCString();
    console.log("Dates are equal: " + (dInStr == dOutStr));
}
```

Usage:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.dateToISO8601String());
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

EDIT

Corrected UTC issue mentioned in comments, and credit to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par#20223090) for the `dateFromISO8601` function.

Comment: this helped me and I think it is a better answer.

Comment: While you are getting the correct local time, you are incorrectly associating that time with zulu time by adding the "Z" in place of the timezone. If you were to take the time created from this and put it into any ISO conforming application, you would *not* get the correct time in return. You should call `.getTimezoneOffset()` and then calculate the minutes into an hours format in place of that in order for your ISO date to be conforming.

Comment: thats wrong and doesnt work Im afraid

Comment: And now you're getting the UTC values but combine them with the local timezone offset?

Comment: The combination with the local timezone offset happens in the date object already. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83Ltp/1/) that illustrates that. If you just want a local string than just build that with the date parts in a concatenation.

Comment: @James I think you should put `.toString()` before `.replace` here `offsetHours.replace("-","") + "00"`.

Comment: As the code is currently, this does not output ISO8601 compliant strings and outputs incorrect times for all but those in UTC timezone.

ISO8601 compliant offsets are in the form `+HH:MM` not `+HH00`.

If you're going to use `+/-NN:NN` suffix for offset hours/minutes that your local timezone is from `Z`, you need to use local Month, Date, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and Milliseconds instead of the UTC versions.

This function should be called `Date.prototype.toLocalISOString` which is more inline with the standard `Date` functions.

`dateFromISO8601` is unnecessary as `new Date()` works.

Comment: Too much bigger to a simple solution.

Comment: This answer computes a UTC string with the timezone offset, which can be useful. However, it does not work for offsets that are not on the hour.

Answer (score 6):

It will be very helpful to get current date and time.

```
var date=new Date();
  var today=new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');
```

Answer (score -3):

Moment js solution to this is

```
var d = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
m.add(m.utcOffset(), 'm')
m.toDate().toISOString()
// output "2019-07-18T00:00:00.000Z"
```