# How could I make this date format in javascript: 2021-03-20T15:59:13+01:00

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

We are using this date format in our app: `2021-03-20T15:42:02+01:00`, but I can't make it with pure javascript.

In the past we used `moment.js`, but I want to avoid it.

In moment, the syntax was the following:

```
moment().format()
//output: 2021-03-20T15:59:13+01:00
```

this was the closest to what I found in pure js...

```
new Date().toISOString()
//output: 2021-03-20T14:59:13.595Z
```

Is there an "easy" way to achieve the same format as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date/time parts the safest is to just build the string from its individual components using the Date `get` methods, and for the UTC offset suffix, you would get the time zone offset, and turn that into hh:mm format:

```js
function localeFormat(date) {
    var offsetMinutes = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    var offset = Math.abs(offsetMinutes);
    return (date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDay()
         + "T" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
        + (offsetMinutes > 0 ? "-" : "+")
        + Math.floor(offset/60) + ":" + Math.abs(offset % 60)
        ).replace(/(\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, "$10$2");
}

console.log(localeFormat(new Date()));
```

Tested on IE9, 10 and 11, current Edge, Firefox and Chrome versions.

Comment: This is the method detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643788/13762301) from the flagged duplicate.

Comment: That answer does not deal with the offset suffix ("+01:00"), @pilchard, which is specific to this question.