# How convert timestamp to specific date and time format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

From api I get a timestamp returned like: `1643295022`

How do I convert it to `2020-08-26T08:46:01+02:00` with Javascript?

```
export const generateDate = (time: number) => {
  return new Date(time * 1000);
};
```

The above returns `Fri Jan 28 2022 12:57:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`. How do I convert it into something like `2022-01-27T14:50:22+02:00`?

Also for another helper I am using already [date-fns](https://date-fns.org). Maybe I can use it in this case?

Comment: `1643295022` looks like it might be too small. Maybe you need to convert it to miliseconds by multiplying by 1000? `new Date(1643295022000)`

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry I was wrong. It's returning now `Fri Jan 28 2022 12:57:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`.  I think I have to use `toISOString()` then it's converted to `2022-01-28T11:57:00.000Z`

Comment: `new Date(1643295022 * 1e3).toISOString()` produces "2022-01-27T14:50:22.000Z". Also see [*How to convert zulu time to UTC +01:00 without moment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816328/how-to-convert-zulu-time-to-utc-0100-without-moment).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an ISO formatted Date but with the Time Zone Offset information.

You can obtain the time zone offset with the `getTimezoneOffset()` then append it to the end of the date format obtained from the `toISOString()` after removing the seconds string after the `.`.

Because the result of the `getTimezoneOffset()` is in minutes you need to convert it into `HH:MM` with the necessary `+` and `-` signs.

Hope the following is of help.

```js
const isoWithTimeZone = d => {
let TZ=(d=new Date(d*1000)).getTimezoneOffset(), a=Math.abs(TZ);
return d.toISOString().split(".")[0]+(TZ<0?"+":"-")+("00"+~~(a/60)).slice(-2)+":"+("00"+a%60).slice(-2);
}

console.log(isoWithTimeZone(1643295022));
```