# JavaScript Date UTC datetime-local

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datetime, datetime-local

I have a form where user can set a date and time with input format datetime-local. When the form is submitted an error appears for the start-date "Value must 11:52 AM or earlier". My local time is 13:52. I have to select -2 hours. How can I remove this problem?

The form is limited for the start date to select only today and last 72 hours, same for end time.

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" id="start_timestamp" required>
<input type="datetime-local" name="end_timestamp" id="end_timestamp" required>

<script>
    //Do not let to select END-TIME and START TIME  in the PAST
    var today = new Date();
    var past = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - 3)).toISOString().slice(0, 16);
    var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);

    document.getElementsByName("start_timestamp")[0].min = past;
    document.getElementsByName("start_timestamp")[0].max = today;
</script>

<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var future = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 3)).toISOString().slice(0, 16);
    var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);

    document.getElementsByName("end_timestamp")[0].min = today;
    document.getElementsByName("end_timestamp")[0].max = future;
</script>
```

I have an image also:

[image]

Comment: You're setting it to the UTC date and time due to *toISOString*, set it to local values instead. Perhaps see [*Javascript date format like ISO but local*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413243/javascript-date-format-like-iso-but-local?r=SearchResults&s=2|131.9156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is timezone related. Because you're using *toISOString* to set the input value, it's being set to UTC date and time, not local. So create a function to return the local time in the correct format.

E.g.

```js
// Format date as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm in local timezone
// to use to set min and max values for inputs
function toISOLocal(date = new Date()) {
  return date.toLocaleString('sv').slice(0,-3).replace(' ','T');
}

/* Initialise date inputs to local dates ± perid in days
 * Start is set to "now", end it set to now ± period
 * @param {string} startID
 * @param {string} endID
 * @param {number} period - ±days from start to end
 */
function initialiseDateInputs(startID, endID, period) {
  let startEl = document.querySelector('#' + startID);
  let endEl = document.querySelector('#' + endID);
  // Ensure elements exist
  if (!startEl || !endEl) return;
  // Create min and max timestamps
  let d = new Date();
  // Create max with zero'd seconds, milliseconds
  let minD = toISOLocal(new Date(d.setSeconds(0,0)));
  // Create min ±period days from max
  let maxD = toISOLocal(new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + period)));
  // If period is -ve, swap max and min
  if (period < 0) {
    [minD, maxD] = [maxD, minD];
  }
  
  // Set element attribute values
  startEl.setAttribute('max', maxD);
  startEl.setAttribute('min', minD);
  startEl.setAttribute('value', period < 0? maxD : minD);
  endEl.setAttribute('max', maxD);
  endEl.setAttribute('min', minD);
  endEl.setAttribute('value', period < 0? minD : maxD);
}

// Run when elements should exist
window.onload = () => {
  initialiseDateInputs('startDate', 'endDate', +3);
}
```

```css
.screenTip {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

input {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span class="screenTip">Start date and time, must be within last 3 days</span><br>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="startDate" id="startDate" required><br>
  
  <span class="screenTip">End date and time, must be within last 3 days</span><br>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="endDate" id="endDate" required><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Setting the input value attribute means that if the inputs are in a form and it's reset, they'll return to the min and max values appropriately.

Comment: Thx for the help and for the explanation now I understood my mistake . It solved my issue :D

Comment: is there a way to set end date to now and + 3 days, and don't allow past dates?
Thx