# How to create new Date() in the format of "2023-12-14T15:11:12-05:00"?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

**Original code**

```js
const start = new Date();

console.log(start);
```

**Result**

```
2023-12-14T20:11:12.388Z
```

My time zone is `America/New_York`, **5 hours behind UTC**.

#### Question

How should I convert a `new Date` object in the format of?

```
2023-12-14T15:11:12-05:00
```

I've been trying things like this but no luck yet,

```js
const start = new Date();

const dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/New_York",
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeStyle: "long"
});

console.log(dateFormat.format(start));
```

Either native JS, or date-fns is fine.

Comment: Not the issue, but what do you expect `console.log` to *return* (as a function) other than `undefined`? Your `d` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @trincot thx, that d was a typo

Comment: Your question sort of suggests converting to an arbitrary time zone based on its name, but since you do say “*My* timezone is `America/New_York`”, are you looking to convert to the browser’s/other runtime’s local time? Because that’s doable in a way with better browser compatibility.

Comment: Logging a `Intl.DateTimeFormat` doesn't show anything interesting. Perhaps you meant `console.log(dateFormat.format(new Date()))`?

Comment: For another duplicate question, see [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17415579/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use toLocaleString() along with some options. There is a trick here as the locale 'sv-SE' (Swedish - Sweden) is used. This is a way to get a more ISO-like date format (YYYY-MM-DD) as it's the default date format for this locale.

```js
const date = new Date();
const options = {
  timeZone: "America/New_York",
  year: 'numeric', 
  month: '2-digit', 
  day: '2-digit', 
  hour: '2-digit', 
  minute: '2-digit', 
  second: '2-digit', 
  timeZoneName: 'longOffset'
};
const dateString = date.toLocaleString('sv-SE', options).replace(' ', 'T').replace(' GMT', '');
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: Answers without explanation are more frequently downvoted than those which explain what the code does an why it was selected over other options.

Comment: Running a small piece of code directly is more convincing than explaining it. @HereticMonkey

Comment: Not if you want to know why the heck someone is in love with Sweden ;-) And this holds until Sweden decides to change their format, which is possible.

Comment: That’s true. It's not that impossible, so I don't know a more decent way to solve this problem, perhaps looking at how third-party libraries such as dayjs implement it might help."

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need to use a library for this.

You can achieve this simply by:

- Grabbing the ISO string
- Removing some bits (milliseconds and Zulu) off the end
- Appending the offset formatted (formatted in HH:MM)

```js
const now = new Date();

// YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'[+-]'HH:MM
console.log(formatLocalDateInIsoWithTimeZone(now));

function formatLocalDateInIsoWithTimeZone(date) {
  const
    offsetMillis = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4,
    offsetDate = new Date(date.getTime() - offsetMillis),
    localDateString = offsetDate.toISOString().replace(/(\.\d{3})?Z$/, '');
  return localDateString + formatOffset(date);
}

function formatOffset(date) {
  const
    offsetInMinutes = date.getTimezoneOffset(),
    sign = offsetInMinutes > 0 ? '-' : '+',
    offset = Math.abs(offsetInMinutes),
    hours = Math.floor(offset / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    minutes = (offset % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return `${sign}${hours}:${minutes}`;
}
```

If you want to do this withe built-in l10n/l16n library, you can use the Swedish locale; as [others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65758103/1762224).

```js
const now = new Date();

const localDateWithTimeZoneFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  timeZoneName: 'longOffset'
});

// YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss'[+-]'HH:MM
console.log(formatLocalDateInIsoWithTimeZone(now));

function formatLocalDateInIsoWithTimeZone(date) {
  return localDateWithTimeZoneFormatter
    .format(date)
    .replace('−', '-')   // time-zone divider
    .replace(' ', 'T')   // date-time divider
    .replace(' GMT', '') // Not needed
}
```

Either way, this is not going to be done in just a few lines of code or the use of a 3rd party library.

Answer (score -2):

Seems [`formatISO` from date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/formatISO) works:

```
import formatISO from 'date-fns/formatISO';

const start = new Date();
console.log(formatISO(start));
```

The output of last run is

```
2023-12-14T16:43:15-05:00
```

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. You don't say what date-fns is or how to implement it. See [answer].

Comment: Does it display timezone as -05:00 or as Z?

Comment: ok, added the output, that's my local time with "-05:00" which is 5 hours behind utc.