# HTML5 Input datetime-local default value of today and current time

Tags: html

Is there anyway that I can make a default value of HTML5 input type='datetime-local' to today's date and this current time.

Thanks before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible. By using a JQuery function, you can have a really complete solution.

Here is an example.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/v8MNx/1/

**HTML**

```
<form action="demo.html" id="myForm">
    <p>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="datetime" name="anniversaire" id="anniversaire"/>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
//Function found here: https://gist.github.com/ryanburnette/8803238
$.fn.setNow = function (onlyBlank) {
  var now = new Date($.now())
    , year
    , month
    , date
    , hours
    , minutes
    , seconds
    , formattedDateTime
    ;

  year = now.getFullYear();
  month = now.getMonth().toString().length === 1 ? '0' + (now.getMonth() + 1).toString() : now.getMonth() + 1;
  date = now.getDate().toString().length === 1 ? '0' + (now.getDate()).toString() : now.getDate();
  hours = now.getHours().toString().length === 1 ? '0' + now.getHours().toString() : now.getHours();
  minutes = now.getMinutes().toString().length === 1 ? '0' + now.getMinutes().toString() : now.getMinutes();
  seconds = now.getSeconds().toString().length === 1 ? '0' + now.getSeconds().toString() : now.getSeconds();

  formattedDateTime = year + '-' + month + '-' + date + 'T' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

  if ( onlyBlank === true && $(this).val() ) {
    return this;
  }

  $(this).val(formattedDateTime);

  return this;
}

$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('input[type="datetime"]').setNow();

});
```

Comment: Warning: input type="datetime" is obsolete, and is already unsupported by most browsers. Use type="datetime-local" instead. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Answer (score 31):

You can make it shorter:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="cal">
```

```js
function toLocalISOString(date) {
  const localDate = new Date(date - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); //offset in milliseconds. Credit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset

  // Optionally remove second/millisecond if needed
  localDate.setSeconds(null);
  localDate.setMilliseconds(null);
  return localDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1);
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("cal").value = toLocalISOString(new Date());
});
```

Comment: In Firefox i had to slice away the seconds (-8) to get the form to validate.

Comment: Best response here, if you want to to remove milliseconds just add `now.setMilliseconds(null)`

Comment: Great answer! And likewise, to remove seconds, use `now.setSeconds(null)`.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer seems pretty complicated to me... here a shorter solution that doesn't need jQuery

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rzaceg8v/

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var utcString = now.toISOString().substring(0,19);
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = now.getDate();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    var localDatetime = year + "-" +
                      (month < 10 ? "0" + month.toString() : month) + "-" +
                      (day < 10 ? "0" + day.toString() : day) + "T" +
                      (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour.toString() : hour) + ":" +
                      (minute < 10 ? "0" + minute.toString() : minute) +
                      utcString.substring(16,19);
    var datetimeField = document.getElementById("myDatetimeField");
    datetimeField.value = localDatetime;
});
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDatetimeField"/>
```

Comment: The default value sets alright, but why doesn't it change when selecting another date/time from the picker?

Comment: That's a good question. It used to work and it still works in Chromium based Edge. I think it may be a bug in the new Chrome version.

Answer (score 6):

The methods above worked but were too verbose for me.
Here's my version:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var adjustedDate = new Date(now.getTime() - offset);
    var formattedDate = adjustedDate.toISOString().substring(0,16); // For minute precision
    var datetimeField = document.getElementById("myDatetimeField");
    datetimeField.value = formattedDate;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly!

One note, I tried this the only month it would break, October. It would give me a '010', instead of 10.

month = (now.getMonth() **+1** ).toString().length === 1 ? '0' + (now.getMonth() + 1).toString() : now.getMonth() + 1;

Answer (score 1):

Big line works for me, if it doesn't for you you can introduce whitespaces and line breaks in the expressions.

```js
    function setDatetimeInput(element, t = new Date()){
        function p(number){return number.toString().padStart(2, '0');}//number to 2 digit, 0 padded string
        element.value = `${t.getFullYear()}-${p(t.getMonth()+1)}-${p(t.getDate())}T${p(t.getHours())}:${p(t.getMinutes())}`;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple way:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="cal">
```

```js
const currentDateTime = () => {
  var tzoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
  var localISOString = new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, -1);

  // convert to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
  const datetimeInputString = localISOString.substring(
    0,
    ((localISOString.indexOf("T") | 0) + 6) | 0
  );
  console.log(datetimeInputString);
  return datetimeInputString;
};

document.getElementById('cal').value = currentDateTime();
```