# Trying to set datetime-local using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code at [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BazzdYJ?editors=1010) codepen to try to populate a `datetime-local` input element with today's data and time. What they have on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime-local_value) tutorial does not work. I also tried what is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159330/convert-an-iso-date-to-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-in-javascript) SO post but also does not seem to work. How do can I set the datetime to today's date and time into a `datetime-local` input element. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime">
```

JS:

```
let today = new Date().toISOString();
document.getElementById('datetime').value = today;
console.log(today);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Input datetime-local default value of today and current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468518/html5-input-datetime-local-default-value-of-today-and-current-time)

Answer (score 6):

You may try this:

```js
let today = new Date();

today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() - today.getTimezoneOffset());
document.getElementById('datetime').value = today.toISOString().slice(0, -1);

console.log(today);
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's the example used on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local):

```
const today = new Date().toISOString();
const dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]');
dateControl.value = today;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```js
 Number.prototype.AddZero= function(b,c){
            var  l= (String(b|| 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
            return l> 0? new Array(l).join(c|| '0')+this : this;
         }//to add zero to less than 10,
         
         
           var d = new Date(),
           localDateTime= [(d.getMonth()+1).AddZero(),
                    d.getDate().AddZero(),
                    d.getFullYear()].join('/') +', ' +
                   [d.getHours().AddZero(),
                    d.getMinutes().AddZero()].join(':');
           var elem=document.getElementById("LocalDate"); 
           elem.value = localDateTime;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="name" id="LocalDate">
```