# Datetime in MST Zone

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, momentjs

On ASP.net MVC application where I save the date on `datetime` field in SQL sever db.It saves like this `2015-04-22 18:43:18.967`.So now I need to show it as `MST (Mountain Standard Time)` on client side.So how can I do that ? I can use `Moment.js` or any other JavaScript library for that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which timezone is your date saved in?

Comment: From the datetime field from SQL, is it a string?  Or is it a date object that you can run methods from?

i.e., can you do datetime.getDate()?

Comment: @Tatermelon I didn't specify any time zone.But I think it takes the default of sql server (may be `GMT`).

Comment: @ChadF `Data Type = datetime` on Sql server.

Comment: @Sampath - In most cases, you should be storing UTC time in the database, but that depends entirely on how you obtained the time to begin with.  Please read [The Case Against `DateTime.Now`](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send the timestamp to the client and you are using momentjs, then it's pretty simple

```
var day = moment(TS_IN_MILLISECONDS).tz('America/Denver')
```

With the string you provided, you can do this:

```
var UTCTime = moment.utc('2015-04-22 18:43:18.967').toDate();
var MSTTime = moment(UTCTime).tz('America/Denver').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: At this moment I'm showing this on client `2015-04-22 18:43:18.967`.So how can I apply above to this datetime ?

Comment: Actually I think you can just pass that string instead of the timestamp. I'm just not certain it will process it as UTC time.

Comment: I updated my answer with how to use the time string you are returning.

Answer (score 0):

So this will depend on what local time your server is running in (or if it's just pulling UTC it'll be a bit easier).  But you can yank the timezone offset like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset): `dateTime.getTimezoneOffset()`, modify it it to reflect the offset difference between your server's timezone and MST.  And then modify your original datetime to reflect the new offset.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset/28149561#28149561) may be a good post for reference.

Also refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048201/4543913):

`dateTime.setTime( dateTime.getTime() + dateTime.getTimezoneOffset()*[math to adjust your timezone] );`