# Date ISO date string issue

Tags: javascript, date

```
console.log(new Date('2016-05-24').toISOString()); // '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
console.log(new Date('05/26/2016').toISOString()); // '2016-05-23T23:00:00.000Z' // why?
```

I am sending data to the server to parse and want to ensure that server will encode my date correctly.

What is the simplest way to convert date to string as '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z' in both cases?

Thanks

Comment: You are aware those are two different dates, right? One is 24 May, one is 26 May.  (That's not the source of the error, though.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: that is just typo ...

Comment: The JavaScript `Date` constructor is well known for accepting an absurd number of different formats and providing completely unpredictable results. Don't push it to the limit ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(new Date('2016-05-24 GMT').toISOString()); // '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
console.log(new Date('05/24/2016 GMT').toISOString()); // '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Append the *timezone* to the date before creating a new date object so that the string parsing code in the `Date` constructor doesn't get confused. Always disambiguate if possible.

Your code was using different timezones for each parse because of the way the dates were formatted. One was using +0 timezone, other was using -1 timezone hence the date being pulled back an hour when the ISO string was created.

Comment: Probably better than my answer - definitely more clean, but the user may not know the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

One is parsing in UTC time, one is parsing in local time.

```
new Date('2016-05-24').toISOString()  // '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
new Date('05/24/2016').toISOString()  // '2016-05-24T07:00:00.000Z'
```

Playing around, here's one solution:

```
new Date(new Date('05/24/2016') - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString() // '2016-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
```

The strategy:

- Create the new offset date
- Subtract the offset
- Create a new date from that result

Reference links:

- [javascript toISOString() ignores timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset)
- [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

---

On further consideration, I'd recommend parsing the date string into something that is "universal" before passing it to the date constructor.  Something like:

```
var tmp = ('05/24/2016').split('//');
var universal = [tmp[2], tmp[0], tmp[1]].join('-'); // 2016-05-24
...
```

Also, [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) does this sort of thing very neatly.

Comment: console.log(new Date(new Date('01/24/2016') - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString()) ??. I need universal way to convert string -> date -> toISOFormat

Comment: I recommend parsing the string with slashes first to get it into a format that's "universal" before passing it to the date constructor.

Comment: I need time to be '00:00:00.000Z' and date 'yyyy-MM-dd' and it should work for all dates. You sample doesn't work for other dates (e.g. console.log(new Date(new Date('01/24/2016') - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString()) ---> 2016-01-24T01:00:00.000Z --> what is wrong)

Comment: You're right, it only works to fix the local offset for slash-format dates.  So, you say you want the date to be `yyyy-mm-dd` but then in the example you have `mm/dd/yyyy`.  You need to decide which one you want, and use that format consistently.  Parse one format into the other when necessary.

Comment: the whole point is to accept different formats and return a consistent result yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm .... Anyway, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use the getDate(), getMonth() and getFullYear() methods to strip out what you need.

Comment: well, it is not what I am looking for. I believe must be better way. Otherwise I would have to add "0" if getDate() < 10 etc ...