# Ignore timezone offset while converting date - javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, date, datetime

I have a WCF REST service that returns date in below format:

```
/Date(1401993000000+0530)/
```

The value of this date on the server is

```
6/6/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to parse this in my javascript code in UTC value.

I tried manually removing the "+0530" string and parsing it to date but it gives "Invalid Date".

I also tried adding the timezone offset as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset) but it gives incorrect value.

How can I parse this?

Comment: This shouldn't give `Invalid Date`: `new Date(1401993000000)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Emphasis on _verifiable_.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm—yes, but the OP needs to apply the offset +0530.

Answer (score 2):

This format is commonly referred to as an "ASP.NET JSON Date" - because it first emerged from the `JavaScriptSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer` classes used in ASP.NET and other parts of .NET.  However, it was [heavily criticized](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx), and ultimately deprecated in favor of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is the default in the [Json.Net](http://json.net) library used in most modern .NET code.  You'll still see it in WCF, and in older versions of ASP.NET MVC.

This format has two main variations:

- `/Date(1401993000000)/` - A timestamp alone
- `/Date(1401993000000+0530)/` - A timestamp with an offset

*You will occasionally see the forward slashes escaped with backslashes, as in `\/Date(1401993000000)\/`, depending on how it was generated.  This should be tolerated by parsers, but should not be depended upon.*

In both formats shown, the timestamp portion is intended to represent the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.

I say "intended", because it is possible in .NET to have a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, which can't possibly be mapped back to UTC.  In this case, the serializer will act as if it had `DateTimeKind.Local`.  The output will then reflect the value adjusted to UTC in the computer's local time zone, along with the computer's UTC offset for that point in time.  Ideally, you should not rely on this behavior, as you will get different results from computers in different time zones.

When an offset is present in the output string, it is in `+HHmm`/`-HHmm` format, with positive values falling East of GMT - the same direction as the ISO 8601 standard.  However, unlike ISO 8601, the value portion is *not* adjusted for that offset.  It remains UTC-based.

In other words:

- `/Date(1401993000000)/` = `2014-06-05T18:30:00Z`
- `/Date(1401993000000+0530)/` = `2014-06-05T18:30:00Z` + `+0530` = `2014-06-06T00:00:00+05:30`

Because of this, the offset portion is extraneous when using this value to create a JavaScript `Date` object - since a `Date` object wraps a timestamp in UTC, and has no provision for retaining a provided offset.

You can certainly break out the string into its parts and use them yourself,
 but instead consider using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for parsing this string.  It understands the format natively, and can give you back an object that retains knowledge of the offset.

```
var m = moment.parseZone("/Date(1401993000000+0530)/");

m.format() // "2014-06-06T00:00:00+05:30"
```

If you were looking for a `Date` object, you can certainly call `m.toDate()`.  The resulting `Date` object will have the same UTC timestamp, but due to how the `Date` object works, any local-time functions will only use the offset of the host environment.

In other words, with output of a `Date` object, the `+0530` part of your input becomes useless.  You might have well have parsed `/Date(1401993000000)/`.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? The OP says "*6/6/2014 12:00:00 AM at the server*" without saying what time zone that is, you're assuming it's +0530 too.

Comment: @RobG - Expanded my answer.  LMK if I missed anything. :)

Comment: Ha!  Dislexia strikes again!  Thanks - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment JS, one of the better ways to play with datetime in JavaSCript. Lot of functions

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

See the edited message, without momentjs:

```js
 var data = [ {"id":1,"start":"/Date(1401993000000+0530)/"} ];
  var myDate = new Date(data[0].start.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
  myDate =  new Date(myDate.getTime() + myDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  alert(myDate);
```

Comment: Although I agree, this isn't really an answer. Merely a comment.
I'd recommend giving the OP a quick example of momentjs solving their issue.

Comment: This gives the wrong result. It adjusts for the host time zone offset when it should adjust for the provided offset (i.e. +0530);