# ion-datetime in ionic2/ionic3, I want to the pop dialog show current date, but ion-datetime not show current date

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="someVar"></ion-datetime>.
```

But if i set today's date to the variable then it will show the value by default. I need to show the date when it is selected only.

Comment: Can you show the `ts` file code?

Comment: main code is `someVar=new Date().toISOString();`

Answer (score 2):

xxx.html

```
<ion-datetime #changeTime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
   [(ngModel)]="changeDate"
   (ionChange)="handleChangeDate(changeDate)"</ion-datetime>
```

xxx.ts

```
@ViewChild('changeTime') changeDateTime: DateTime;

changeDate = '';
constructor() {
        let datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
        this.changeDate = datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.changeDateTime.updateText = () => {};
}

handleChangeDate(changeDate: string) {
        this.changeDate = changeDate;
        this.changeDateTime._text = changeDate;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Is that working for you?  Can we have a `plunker` or `stackblitz`?

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9846

If you're using Ionic 3.7 or later, they've added a feature to set `initialValue` on the `ion-dateime` element. (Hooray! Thanks to [mlynch](https://github.com/mlynch))

Example:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="someDateControl" (initialValue)="10/01/2017"></ion-datetime>
```

The same approach should work w/an `ngModel` template-driven form as well.

Preferable to set `(initialValue)="someDateFunction()"` rather than hard-coding the date.

In the component's .ts file, [to return the current local date/time for your timezone (instead of default GMT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset), you could have:

```
someDateFunction() {
  let timezoneOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //offset in milliseconds
  let localDateTime = (new Date(Date.now() - timezoneOffset)).toISOString().slice(0,-1);

  return localDateTime;
}
```

This defaults the `ion-datetime` minimum value to today's date based on the user's location, but leaves the field blank until a date is actually selected and committed. If you want to automatically set it 1 month out or something similar, you just need to adjust the dateFunction.

Comment: I am on 3.12 and this does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Not an official solution but a better workaround in your case.

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0KJ7xR?p=preview).

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Select Date</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Text Input" [value]="dataInicial | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (click)="open()"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item no-lines hidden="true">
      <ion-datetime #datePicker displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" (ionCancel)="this.dataInicial  = null" [(ngModel)]="dataInicial" doneText="Feito" cancelText="Cancelar" [max]="maxDate">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'app/home.page.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

     appName = 'Ionic App';
     dataInicial: Date;
     maxDate: string;

     constructor(public neavController: NavController) {}
     @ViewChild('datePicker') datePicker;
     open() {
         if (!this.dataInicial) {
             this.dataInicial = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.datePicker.open();
             }, 50)
         } else {
             this.datePicker.open();
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I want the pop dialog show current date, but the ion-date don't show it, and it show the date when it is selected only.

Comment: yeah, thank you. I saw it. I found the answer also, but it can't meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2021
ionic 5

Still Not an official solution So i'm going with work around:

Declare a variable in the component code, say intialDate, and initialize it to an empty string ""
In the template  mark up, set intialDate as the [(ngModel)] and add an event handler to the (tap) event
In the component code of the (tap) event handler, set intialDate to the date you want the datetime to open with (check for state and apply logic accordingly)
Handle the ionCancel event yourself and reset everything as per the state and app logic

xxx.html

`<ion-datetime (tap)="dateFocus(intialDate)" (ionCancel)="intialDate.value = null" #inputRefDate2='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="intialDate" [name]="intialDate" displayFormat="DD-MMM-YYYY" pickerFormat="DD-MMM-YYYY"> </ion-datetime>`

xxx.ts

`dateFocus(obj) {if (!obj.value) {obj.value = new Date(this.currentDate).toISOString();}}`