# Calling toISOString() thows "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked."

Tags: angular, iso8601

I have this method here in a component:

```js
getTime(): Date {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setHours(this.hour);
  date.setMinutes(this.minute);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  return date;
}
```

which I call within another:

```xml
<input matInput [hidden]="true" formControlName="time"
           [ngModel]="this.timePicker.getTime().toISOString()"/>
```

However, even though the `string` gets correctly generated (at least that's how the JSON looks like):

```
"time": "2017-11-14T10:30:00.271Z"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
CreateGroupComponent.html:40 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '2017-11-14T10:30:00.338Z'. Current value: '2017-11-14T10:30:00.341Z'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:9514)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9492)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9661)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13674)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13646)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (
```

I see this error only if I call `toISOString()`. If I just return the `Date` object it's fine but converting it to an ISO string gives me that exception. Why?

---

Talking about `toISOString()` - where's actually the timezone information in

```
2017-11-14T10:30:00.271Z
```

? For me, it's actually supposed to be

```
2017-11-14T10:30:00.271Z+01:00
```

Comment: Btw, why are ngModel and form control there at the same time? Usually they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because milliseconds change on each `getTime` call, this is what the error says.

It should be:

```
getTime(): Date {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setHours(this.hour);
  date.setMinutes(this.minute);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);  
  return date;
}
```

Regarding timezone, [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) states,

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601) <...>. The timezone is **always zero UTC offset**, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

If local time is expected, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset) for possible solutions.