# Are references to Date object inside a map function carried over?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datetime

I am running into a weird issue where the dates in a function I have are being written to objects (and then stored) are having some side effects.

```js
const normalizedEntries = allEntries.map((item) => {
  const dateObj = new Date(item.timestamp * 1000);
  const groupedDate = new Date(item.timestamp * 1000);
  groupedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  console.log(dateObj);
  console.log(groupedDate);
  const normalizedEntry: NormalizedEntry = {
    sites: item.sites,
    date: dateObj.toISOString(),
    groupedDate: groupedDate.toISOString(),
  };
  console.log(normalizedEntry);
  return normalizedEntry;
});
```

All I am trying to do in this function is take in an object that has a timestamp and a number (the sites field) and produce this new typed object `NormalizedEntry` which you can see has the original date, the sites (number) and a grouped date (which is just the day but with the time set to zero so I can group multiple objects later in redux).

Within the first two passes of the loop (for now I am working with a small set - 300, of test data) the data begins to get out of whack and I don't understand why. Is there something going on with the references of the dates? Or perhaps something about dates I do not understand yet? Below is the output of those console logs from above

```json
// iteration one
Wed Jan 20 2021 17:16:49 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Wed Jan 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
{sites: 26, date: "2021-01-20T22:16:49.000Z", groupedDate: "2021-01-20T05:00:00.000Z"}
// iteration two
Wed Jan 20 2021 20:27:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Wed Jan 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
{sites: 41, date: "2021-01-21T01:27:58.000Z", groupedDate: "2021-01-20T05:00:00.000Z"}
```

As you can see the `console.log(dadte)` prints out the correct thing in the second iteration but for some reason when setting it to the object below it says it's on the 21st versus the 20th which it clearly is 5 lines above. This is in turn throwing all of my data out of whack.

EDIT:
Now trying to resolve it being a timezone issue as pointed out from below but this is still not resolving the issue:

```js
const normalizedEntries = allEntries.map((item, idx) => {
  let originDate = new Date(item.timestamp * 1000);

  const timezoneDifference = originDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  const correctedDate = new Date(
    originDate.setHours(originDate.getHours() + timezoneDifference, 0, 0, 0)
  );

  let groupedDate = correctedDate;
  groupedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  console.log(originDate.toString());
  console.log(groupedDate.toString());
  const normalizedEntry: NormalizedAcquisition = {
    sites: item.sites,
    date: originDate.toISOString(),
    groupedDate: groupedDate.toISOString(),
  };
  return normalizedEntry;
});
```

Comment: You don’t have to change anything. You are comparing timestamps with -5:00 offset generated by *toString* to timestamps with +0:00 offset generated by *toISOString*. They represent the same moment in time, they just have different offsets. I.e. Wed Jan 20 2021 17:16:49 GMT-0500 is the same as 2021-01-20T22:16:49.000Z and Wed Jan 20 2021 20:27:58 GMT-0500 is the same as 2021-01-21T01:27:58.000Z.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the timezone

The dates have gmt -5
You set hours to 0 in that timezone

When you format as iso it uses gmt

You need to get the timezone and take into account when setting the time to 00:00

See mdn [date.getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: That makes sense. So would I then `setHours( 0+timezoneDifference, 0+timezoneDifference, 0+timezoneDifference, 0+timezoneDifference)` - Just did that for clarity since I cant do a code block in the comment

Comment: See the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830357/javascript-toisostring-ignores-timezone-offset format your string this way and you should get what you need

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please provide a snippet. When I try and `setHours(date.getHours() + tzOffset, 0, 0, 0)` it is bumping up the days and not the hours.

Comment: It is minus, not plus, tzOffset