# Inline datepicker in grid not persisting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, date, kendo-ui

I have a grid which takes a date from a MySQL database in the format year-month-day hour:minute:second and displays it as a UK date in a datepicker in the grid. This seems to work fine.

As soon as I go to edit the date in the inline editor though, I can make the change but it the editor immediately exits, taking me back to the original grid.

Note that I am using jQuery 1.8.2

Just wondering if anyone else has seen this before? I get an "unexpected number" error, which makes me think it might have something to do with the date formatting, but Chrome's debugging capabilities end there, pointing to the Kendo and jQuery libraries, not my code (which is obviously not what I want).

I *think* Kendo and Javascript in general use slightly different date format representations, which might be something to do with this.

This is my the code that makes the grid:

```
                 kendo.culture("en-GB");
             $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                 dataSource: {
                     transport: {
                         read: {
                            url: "http://dev.openbill.co.uk/admin/crud/viewproject/main.json.php?action=read&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json"
                         },
                         update: {
                            url: "http://dev.openbill.co.uk/admin/crud/viewproject/main.json.php?action=update&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
                            type: "POST"
                         },
                         destroy: {
                             url: "http://dev.openbill.co.uk/admin/crud/viewproject/main.json.php?action=destroy&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
                             type: "POST"
                          },
                          create: {
                              url: "http://dev.openbill.co.uk/admin/crud/viewproject/main.json.php?action=create&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
                              type: "POST"
                           },
                     },
                    schema: {
                        data: "data",
                        total: "total",
                        parse: function(response) {

                            for (var i = 0; i < response["data"].length; i++) {
                                //Parsing the data before its used
                                //"17\/10\/2012 20:55:00"
                                var phpStartDate = response["data"][i]["start"];
                                var phpStopDate = response["data"][i]["stop"];
                                var datePartsStart = phpStartDate.match(/(\d+)/g);
                                var datePartsStop = phpStopDate.match(/(\d+)/g);
                                var parsedDateStart = new Date(datePartsStart[0], datePartsStart[1], datePartsStart[2], datePartsStart[3], datePartsStart[4], datePartsStart[5]);
                                var parsedDateStop = new Date(datePartsStop[0], datePartsStop[1], datePartsStop[2], datePartsStop[3], datePartsStop[4], datePartsStop[5]);

                                response["data"][i]["start"] = parsedDateStart;
                                response["data"][i]["stop"] = parsedDateStop;
                                //debugger;
                            };
                            return response;
                        },
                        model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                                id: {editable: false,nullable: false},
                                start: {
                                    editable: true,
                                    nullable: false,
                                    type: "date",
                                    format: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                    validation: {required: true}
                                },
                            stop: {
                                    editable: true,
                                    nullable: true,
                                    type: "date",
                                    format: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                    validation: {required: true}
                                },
                            staff: {editable: true,nullable: false},
                            hourly: {editable: true,nullable: false},
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                     serverPaging: true,
                     serverSorting: true,
                     pageSize: 10,
                     page: 1,
                    scrollable: {
                        virtual: true
                     },
                    sort: { field: "start", dir: "asc"}
                    },
                 sortable: true,
                 selectable: false,
                 resizable: true,
                 reorderable: true,
                 toolbar: ["create"],
                 editable: "inline",
                 pageable: {
                        numeric: false,
                        pageSizes: [ 10 , 25, 50 ],
                        previousNext: true,
                        input: true,
                        info: true
                },
                 columns: [
                        { field:"id", title:"Tracking ID", hidden: true},
                        { field:"start", title:"Start Time", editor: startDateEditor, template: '#= kendo.toString(start,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") #' },
                        { field:"stop", title:"End Time", editor: endDateEditor, template: '#= kendo.toString(stop,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") #' },
                        { field:"staff", title:"Staff Member", editor: staffEditor },
                        { field:"hourly", title:"Hourly Rate", editor: hourlyEditor, width: 90 },
                        { command: "edit", width: 175  },
                        { command: "destroy", width: 90  },
                        { template: '<input type="checkbox" name="#=id#" />', width: 40  },
                    ],
            });
            function startDateEditor(container, options){
                $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDateTimePicker({

                    });
            }
            function endDateEditor(container, options){
                $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDateTimePicker({

                    });
            }
            function staffEditor(container, options) {
                $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-value-field="id" />')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        autoBind: true,
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataValueField: "id",
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://dev.openbill.co.uk/admin/crud/viewproject/staff.json.php"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "data",
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
            function hourlyEditor(container, options) {
                $('<input min="0" type="number" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" />')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoNumericTextBox({
                        format: "c",
                        decimals: 2
                    });
            }
```

Comment: I'd use Firebug to get a little more info. You can download it for chrome too. Doing some 'console.log(date)' to look into possible discrepancies in date format could help.

Comment: what version of Kendo UI are you using? Past version were not fully compatbile with 1.8 +

Comment: You should have at least version 2012.2.710

Answer (score 0):

This may be relevant:

The one big difference between dates in PHP and Javascript is the way months get counted. In PHP, 1 is January. In Javascript, 0 is January. So, you literally need to subtract one from a MySQL php date to get the right date in JS.

Look at this thread: [Stack Overflow — Conver JS Date Object to MySQL format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280104/convert-javascript-to-date-object-to-mysql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)