# correctly formatting javascript date to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm creating a JavaScript based calendar, using full-calendar.js as main backbone.
So in other to insert a new `event` into a MySQL database, I have the following code snippet:

```
$.post("http://localhost/calendar/index.php/calendar/insert_event", 
      { 
        title  : title,
        start  : start,
        end    : end,
        allDay : allDay,
        url    : ''
      }, 
      function(answer) {
        console.log(answer);
      }
);
```

the `start` and `end` dates are simply `Date()` objects:

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
```

in the `calendar.php` controller, I get the following output:

```
{"title":"lunch",
 "start":"Tue Oct 08 2013 08:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)",
 "end":"Tue Oct 08 2013 08:30:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)",
 "allDay":"false",
 "url":""}
```

`start` and `end` are `DATETIME` Types in a MySQL table where the columns have the same type was above.
When I do the `insert` using `CodeIgniter's` Active Record functions, it inserts to the table without further problems. However, when I look at the `MySQL` database to see the output, I see:

```
mysql> select * from calendar_utility;
+----+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | url | title | start               | end                 | allday |
+----+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 |     | lunch | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |      0 |
+----+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I correct format the `JavaScript` `Date()` to insert correctly at the MySQL db?

Comment: forgive me, I was wrong, `strtotime` doesn't work as nice :) Just convert Date object to mysql datetime string. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280104/convert-javascript-to-date-object-to-mysql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: That has been done before, take a look a this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452892/2131277

Answer (score 5):

I would probably convert the JS `Date` objects to strings conforming to the MySQL `DATETIME` format like this:

```
$.post("http://localhost/calendar/index.php/calendar/insert_event", 
      { 
        title  : title,
        start  : start.getFullYear() + "-" + (start.getMonth()+1) + "-" + start.getDate() + " " + start.getHours() + ":" + start.getMinutes() + ":" + start.getSeconds(),
        end    : end.getFullYear() + "-" (end.getMonth()+1) + "-" + end.getDate() + " " + end.getHours() + ":" + end.getMinutes() + ":" + end.getSeconds(),
        allDay : allDay,
        url    : ''
      }, 
      function(answer) {
        console.log(answer);
      }
);
```

Comment: Not that there is a missing `+` concatenator between `-` and `(start.getMonth()+1)` that is causing an error. Stackoverflow won't allow me to make "edits" of less than 6 characters.