# How to Convert solr date to javascript date?

Tags: java, solr, datetime-conversion

i am having the time in "2016-11-17T09:22:24Z" and i need to convert it into
"2016-11-1709:22:24".Just need to remove T and Z from solr Date and i need to add 330 minutes to that date and display it

Comment: As per the title of the question, he actually needs a Javascript date, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userdate = new Date("2009-1-1T8:00:00Z");
var timezone = userdate.getTimezoneOffset();
var serverdate = new Date(userdate.setMinutes(userdate.getMinutes()+parseInt(timezone)));
```

This will give you the proper UTC Date and Time.
It's because the getTimezoneOffset() will give you the timezone difference in minutes. I recommend you that not to use toISOString() because the output will be in the string Hence in future you will not able to manipulate the date

Answer (score 1):

First we can construct a javascript date object from the string and then you can convert it into correct format:

```
var dt = new Date('2016-11-17T09:22:24Z')
var formattedDate = dt.toISOString().substring(0, 19).replace('T', '')
```

`console.log(formattedDate)` should log `2016-11-1709:22:24`

Or in one line:

```
new Date('2016-11-17T09:22:24Z').toISOString().substring(0, 19).replace('T', '')
```

will render: `2016-11-1709:22:24`

Some more good discussions here: [Convert javascript to date object to mysql date format (YYYY-MM-DD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280104/convert-javascript-to-date-object-to-mysql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: JavaScript does not really have a specific date format. Your current Solr date format is good enough for Javascript to understand. For example: `new Date('2016-11-17T09:22:24Z')`  will give a JavaScript date.

Comment: but when i am converting formatted date into date it is showing invalid date

Comment: new date(formattedDate);
this shows the error of invalid date

Comment: `formattedDate` is already a date object. You do not have to convert it. I am updating the answer a bit to show you a one liner solution in case it helps you.

Comment: i also need to add 330 mins in it how can i add it?

Comment: just run: `dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 330)` and now `dt` should have 330+ mins

Comment: i was doing the same thing but set and get method is not supported to that dt object.
it shows the error that object does not support the getMinutes method

Comment: thank you for the help i got the output from the the below code

Comment: var publish = new Date("2016-11-17T09:22:24Z");
 var min =  publish.setMinutes(publish.getMinutes() + parseInt(330));
 var dt = new Date(min);
 alert(dt);